# JavaCV - UnsatisfiedLinkError when used together with Vitamio library

Tags: android, javacv, vitamio

I'm trying to make an application than can stream live video to RTMP server (I'm using [this](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/RecordActivity.java) example) and a way to play the video (I'm using the vitamio library).

I tried the JavaCV example and it was running just fine. But, after I added the vitamio library to my project, the application now gives this error.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
```

at this line:

```
recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(ffmpeg_link, imageHeight, imageWidth, 1);
```

What's the reason for this is to happen? Removing the vitamio library will solve the problem, but I want to use these two libraries together if possible.

Comment: I have the same problem and it's not only vitamio causes UnsatisfiedLinkError but adding other libraries like "pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.17" causes error too.